# Multiple Column in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

i have a table where id is Primary key and there are other information like house no,city,address,contract etc.But i want to add one or more contact number against a single id since a person can have one or more cell number.I have created different table for phone numbers only.what way would be better for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

you can store phone numbers in json format. use php function `json_encode($array_name)` . and while fetching use `json_decode(column_name)`. in foreach loop get all the values. This will be the best solution.
Or you can use implode and explode by (,) comma separated phone numbers.